# convert hashmap to lower case

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I want to convert hashmap elements into lower case . In my code i have coverted retMap to lower case but its not reflecting when i am printing RetMap .Please help me where m going wrong.

```
public HashMap<String,String> loadHashmapFromResultset(ResultSet rs, String sKey, String sValue) throws SQLException
{
    //HashMap<String,String> myMap
    HashMap<String,String> RetMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    while(rs.next()){
        //System.out.print(rs.getString(sKey)+rs.getString(sValue)+", " );
        RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey.toLowerCase()), rs.getString(sValue.toLowerCase()));
    }
System.out.print(RetMap);
    return RetMap;
}

       results = stmt.executeQuery("select xyz,abc from table1");
        HashMap<String,String> INVS_VALUES = new HashMap<String,String>();
        INVS_VANITY_VALUES=util.loadHashmapFromResultset(results, "xyz", "abc");
        System.out.println("INVS_VALUES: "+INVS_VALUES);
```

Comment: Naming conventions. `INV_VALUES` is not part of them.

Comment: Are you looking for `RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey).toLowerCase(), ...)` ? Because your current code is putting in lower case the parameters you pass to your method, which are already in lower case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lowercase the key and the value you get as parameters:

```
RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey.toLowerCase()), rs.getString(sValue.toLowerCase()));
```

You should lowercase the actual results:

```
RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey).toLowerCase(), rs.getString(sValue).toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you've changed the case of only the `sKey` and `sValue` which are used as column names to fetch String from the `ResultSet`. You need to convert the case of actual values you're putting the map as `key and value` to lowercase.

```
RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase(), rs.getString(sValue.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase());
```

In case you mistakenly changed the case of they `sKey` and `sValue`, then you can simply use this.

```
RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey).toLowerCase(), rs.getString(sValue).toLowerCase());
```

[As mentioned in the comments by sura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725225/convert-hashmap-to-lower-case/21725297#comment32853493_21725297), you could add a `null` check before calling the `toLowercase()` on the Strings returned from the `ResultSet` to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Comment: better if you can do a null check before call toLowerCase

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED...I DID RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey).toLowerCase(), rs.getString(sValue).toLowerCase());

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RetMap.put(rs.getString(sKey).toLowerCase(), rs.getString(sValue).toLowerCase());
```